# Revert migration on deleted not null field

Tags: django, database-migration

I've got a model with a non-null field which I deleted:

```
class Spam(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True)  # deleted
```

After I made the migrations and applied them, I wanted to revert them.
But obviously, this results in

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: eggs_spam.slug
```

How can I revert the migration?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's tricky. The only solution I can think of is the following:

1: First, create a migration that allows the slug field to be nullable

2: Then, create another migration that will populate the field for every row

3: Lastly, create a migration that makes the field non-nullable.

Hope it helps

Comment: How can I do that once the slug has already been deleted and I cannot revert it?

Comment: @Joren as I said: you should add it back but make it nullable first. Then, create a data migration that fills every row with some value. Then, create a not null constraint.

Comment: Ahh yes I understand, this worked. Too bad I now have 4 extra migrations due to a mistake made during development

Comment: @Joren 4 extra is not that bad. If the app is not in production, you can always delete your database, and run `makemigrations` once again.

Answer (score 15):

There is an easier way:

1. Find migration where you have initially add slug field
2. Add default value to slug field
3. Unapply last migration
4. Remove default value from initial slug field migration